# What to consider security wise, when having a mail catch-all policy?

Tags: email

> ... a catch-all usually refers to a mailbox on a domain that will "catch all" of the emails addressed to the domain that do not exist in the mail server. Configuring a catch-all address can help avoid losing emails due to misspelling. However, many email hosts no longer permit catch-alls since many spammers abuse the feature, spamming random email addresses. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all)

What to consider, security wise when having a mail catch-all policy? Or is having a mail catch-all policy somehow an (availability) risk because all emails will be processed and so it seems easier to cause resource exhaustion I guess?

What are the pro's and con's (security wise) of having such a policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROS

- Less likely to lose an email due to human error on the sending side.

CONS

- If you're running anti-spam / antivirus that's scanning incoming emails for malware that scanning process *can* occur in the kernel to speed up the process. Any vulnerability in your antivirus / anti-spam (cough) [Symantec](http://www.securityweek.com/critical-vulnerability-symantec-av-engine-can-be-exploited-sending-email) could result in unnecessary exposure to exploit.
- Depending on your antispam, if the resources for that AS is exhausted they can just freeze and stop processing emails, delivering them unscanned. I have seen antispam agents (albiet, less known & used ones) panic due to resource exhaustion and while the service was restarting email was delivered without being sanitized.
- The addition of unncessary logs will make reviewing anti-spam logs cumbersome and if you should ever need them for foresnsics it will be that much more tedious to find what you're looking for.
- The Pro is not really a great reason because NDR's should serve the purpose of notifying the sender in the instance the email address is incorrect. Granted that may not be the most desirable in instances where business can be lost due to emails not being delivered, but to me the cons outweigh the pros.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.

Catch-all policy introduces the risk that a confidential email will end up being read by an unintended person (someone viewing the catch-all inbox) if the sender makes a  typo error in the recipient address.  It is far preferable for the email to bounce and a notification sent to be sent the sender, who can correct the address and send it again.

Comment: Wouldn't the email admins be able to read all emails anyway? Where is the increased risk?

Comment: Admins can grant themselves any permission they want but access to SVP, HR, and sales emails should be blocked by default with any changes controlled by an audit process.

Comment: How does one block an email admin from only certain dept emails? And auditing controls are not preventative controls. You could set up the same thing on a 'catch-all'.

Comment: Here's [how](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/685062f2-b877-4a5e-8544-536d576d3677/prevent-administrator-read-email?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy).  Sure, you could monitor and audit any access to the catchall inbox, but that would result in an untenable number of false positives.

Comment: That link does not appear to be relevant to preventing admins from reading emails because it takes Enterprise Exchange Admins to remove permissions: meaning that the admins can restore the permissions. Note that many of the answers talk about the need to trust the Admins.

Comment: My organization has hundreds of admins and thousands of clients with whom we sign NDA and who are themselves governed by confidentiality agreements and data handling standards.  If you are serious about security, you can't just trust your admins, you have to audit them.  You revoke their permissions and get the system to log it if they restore them.  That way you have an audit trail in case there are any lawsuits or other complications.  "Just trust the admins" is not much of an answer frankly.

Comment: And auditing does not diminish the risks of data disclosure, which appears to be your point ....  Your answer hangs on the line "introduces the risk that a confidential email will end up being read by an unintended person" which would appear to need to be a trusted admin. You have not explained how a risk is introduced that does not already exist even in a "block some dept emails" setup.

Comment: That is flat wrong, you can assign access permissions to a catch-all inbox to nearly anybody... and depending on the volume, you would not exactly assign your senior administrator!  And if you do not  understand the importance of auditability in a comprehensive security plan, I doubt further discussion with you will be very informative.

Comment: You could also assign Enterprise Exchange Admin permissions to anyone ... And if you really do work in an org with hundreds of admins, then you likely have a DLP department who reviews all levels of classified documents. You don't have to assign a senior exchange admin. And yes, I do understand that auditing is a *detective* control, not a *preventative* control, which is the entirety of my point in regards to the risk being treated here....

Answer (score 0):

Spammers sometimes try out many addresses on the same host:

- a@example.com
- b@example.com
- c@example.com
- etcetera

If you have a catch-all address all these e-mails will be delivered in your inbox. If the spammer sent a lot of mail this will break your e-mail system, or at least take a lot of time to handle.